# How to call a function only once inside mouseover function in typescript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7

I am using angular7. In my application I am showing a list of places. when i hover on any one place I am calling an ajax function to store that value in database.

But when I hover on any one element, that ajax function get called multiple times. I want to call that function only once.

Here is my angular code:

```html
<div *ngFor="let place of mapData" (mouseover)="displayTagInfo($event)">
  <div class="filter-name">{{place.name}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add a variable which is visible to the scope of your document, eg. var doOnce = false, then inside your function if ( doOnce == false) { return; } doOnce = true;

Comment: @SPlatten where should i call my ajax function? and if I hover on another element of ngFor is that my ajax function get call again?

Comment: You could pass another property to the function or get the function to query the ID of the element it is triggered from then instead of a single variable create a JavaScript object which you populate with the ID then test for the presence of the ID and use its existance as a flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a key `hovered = false` in mapData array object that is initially false, so for each element you have `hovered = false` pass that particular place, object to `displayTagInfo($event,place)`

```
<div *ngFor="let place of mapData" (mouseover)="displayTagInfo($event,place)">
  <div class="filter-name">{{place.name}}</div>
</div>
```

In .ts

```
displayTagInfo(event,place){
  if(!place.hovered){
    //Do what you want to do, HERE

    place.hovered = true;
  }
}
```

This way you will be able to hover each element once only... Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is:
inside the function you call you can add a boolean variable that tracks whether or not the event has already fired.

> you need to initialize the variable inside the contructor of the
>   component you want to track it in.

```
function displayTagInfo(event){
    if (this.tagInfoDisplayHasBeenFired) {
        return;
    }

    this.tagInfoDisplayHasBeenFired = true

   //Your code
}
```